# Link Outlook email message to Microsoft Project Task

Tags: outlook, ms-office, ms-project

I would like to attach a specific email message from my outlook to a specific Microsoft Project task as a link or attachment.

I am using Microsoft Office 2013.

Is there an option to do that?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to save the email message to the hard drive (see the SaveAs method of the Attachment class) and then add it as an attachment to the Project task. See [How to: Add an Attachment in Microsoft Excel or Microsoft Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514161(v=vs.90).aspx) for more information.

Note, you can use the Macro Recorder in MSProject to generate the required macro stub automatically.